# MVC 4 / Razor in layman's terms

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm sorry if this is a stupid or obvious question, but I've spent the better part of a week researching, and I really can't find any resources that explain what MVC 4 and Razor are, and what they are intended to do in web development. I'm not necessarily asking for a really detailed description, even a link to a website or the name of a book that doesn't explain MVC 4 by referencing other technologies that I have also never used. I've looked through articles, articles and tutorials on everything from MSDN to graduate papers and I just don't get it.

I know what MVC the design pattern is, but one of the main things I can't get a straight answer to is what the difference is between MVC the pattern and MVC 4 the framework. As a web developer, will I ever have to change or make use of the frameworks, or is it something that is supposed to "stay out of your way" (to quote another SO post.) Is it something that gets generated by VS and I will never have to touch?

Again, I'm sorry if this is obvious, maybe I'm trying to make this more complicated than it actually is. All I have been looking for is a straight forward answer with concrete examples that don't contradict or complicate it any further.

Please...I'm at my wits end here. My last question was apparently too vague and got voted down and closed, so I tried to be more specific, but part of my problem is what are the right questions to ask.If there is anything that can say to clarify,please tell me.

Comment: have you tried to read the http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/overview/asp-net-mvc-overview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I certainly don't want to discourage you any more than you appear to be at the moment, but in my opinion, if you can't make head or tail of the huge amount of material that already exists on MVC, then perhaps you are just not ready for it yet. That's OK - in fact Microsoft recognise that MVC is complicated, which is why they introduced the [ASP.NET Web Pages framework](http://www.asp.net/web-pages) (which is what gave birth to Razor syntax).

My advice would be to follow the link and download WebMatrix. Then follow some of the Web Pages tutorials. That way you can get your head around Razor without worrying too much about MVC for the time being.

Incidentally, ASP.NET MVC is a web development framework that enables you to build web applications based on the MVC pattern. You need to understand how MVC works in order to make use of the framework. You need to understand what Models are, what Views are and the role that Controllers play in the whole thing.

The framework itself is not an example of MVC.

Razor is a templating syntax that allows you to intermix C# (or VB) with HTML to output dynamic content in a View in MVC or a page in the Web Pages framework.

Comment: I would be the first to agree with that, unfortunately I'm in a class that I can't drop and I have to make the best of it. I am very familiar with MVC, the design pattern, but it was very clear to me that MVC and MVC 4 (the framework) were similar, but not the same thing. I really appreciate the help though; I actually did see that site, but I had a different idea of what the framework was, so I was looking for the wrong thing. Thank you again, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Added a bit more to my answer in the hope that it adds clarification

Answer (score 2):

I know it may seem confusing, but it seems to me that you are over complicating things.

The simple matter is that MVC is a design pattern.  That is, it's an abstract thing.. a philosophy of sorts.  It's not a concrete thing.  A design pattern simply gives you a description of how the pattern is supposed to work, and while it may give you a sample implementation, in general it leaves that implementation up to you.

ASP.NET MVC (whichever version) is a specific application framework that uses the MVC pattern as its basis.  In other words, it's a concrete implementation of the MVC design pattern.

In fact, the ASP.NET MVC implementation isn't even a "true" implementation of the MVC design pattern, as certain compromises are necessary to make it work in a web based model.  So it's really more "MVC design pattern inspired".

You're overthinking things.  Just accept that ASP.NET MVC is a framework library that implements and MVC design pattern.

As for Razor, it's merely a templating library.  That is, it allows you to define a page layout as text, and insert values at specific places (place-holders).  It also allows code to be executed during the process of rendering a template, although this is discouraged in MVC except for very simple cases.

Razor is also used in ASP.NET WebPages technology, in those cases it tends to be more like PHP or classic asp in that all code exists in code blocks within the template itself.  Both ASP.NET and WebPages use the Razor templating engine (also called a View Engine) but they use them in different ways.